# separate the background and foreground

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-learn, image-segmentation

I have an image as such:
What is the best way in python to separate the background and foreground?

[image]

Comment: take a loog at [GrabCut](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html#gsc.tab=0)

Comment: @Shai Is there a tool that doesn't require user interaction?

Comment: the user-provided rectangle does not necessarily has to be tight and accurate. if it is safe enough in your case to say that the object is not located in the boundary of the frame, then you can use this as the input to `GrabCut` for segmentation.

Comment: If you don't want *user interaction* you need some knowledge of what you are looking for. Is quite difficult for a computer vision algorithm to blindly extract from an image what you are looking for. The image you show is quite tricky since a human eye can *follow* the whatever that fish is inside the water, but a computer algorithm will get troubles distinguishing it from water. In other words, the short answer is NO, you can't do without user interaction, the long answer is in general YES, but you would require a LOT of knowledge of what you are doing.

Comment: @imaluengo even for a ruff estimate? Really what I need is just a box around the whale.

Comment: Then you should clarify your question. Separate foreground from background is usually called "Background substraction" and has several links with "image segmentation" which is hard, extracting a bounding box around the object is called "Object detection" (or "Object tracking" if its in a time series) and is significantly *easier*. All depends in the accuracy of your desired "extraction", if you want a ruff estimate it would be *doable*, if you want an accurate extraction it would be much much harder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If what you want is an estimate of where your object is, you can use the *color* of the image to get an idea. All the bellow steps are done using [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/). The operations are pretty basic, a simple thresholding (the most basic image processing tool) in **Lab** colorspace. If you want something more complex without user interaction, it would require significantly more effort.

0) Import packages

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io, color
```

1) Load the image

```
rgb = io.imread('your_image_path')
```

2) Transform the image to [**Lab** colorspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space). The Lab colorspace gives in general better color separability for most applications.

```
img = color.rgb2lab(rgb)
```

3) Threshold the Lab colorspace

```
thresholded = np.logical_and(*[img[..., i] > t for i, t in enumerate([40, 0, 0])])
```

The line above basically thresholds the image and sets to **1** all the pixels that are `>40` in the first channel (**L**), and `>0` in the 2nd and 3rd channels (**a, b**), sets the pixels that break any of those conditions to **0**.

4) Show results:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
ax[0].imshow(rgb);         ax[0].axis('off')
ax[1].imshow(thresholded); ax[1].axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

As explained above, this a very quick (not too good) result, but should be enough to get you a bounding box. You can then extract the `ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax` from the `thresholded` image, and you would have the bounding box of your object.

Comment: super answer. Thx for that. I have a question, why 40? is there any good rule to define that number?

Comment: It was selected after trial and error. That number is image specific. The reasoning behind it is the scaling of the L channel in Lab. In this particular case, tresholding > 40 suppresses all the non-bright pixels (L is luminance).